# Change Repeater Index at runtime

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, vb.net, asprepeater

I am having a repeater control populated with 4 values.

1 Class_1
2 Class_2
3 Class_4
4 Class_3

Repeater is bind on index value, so when repeater is displayed it display data as:
 Class_1
 Class_2
 Class_4
 Class_3.

But I want to show data as:

Class_1
 Class_2
 **Class_3

 Class_4.**

I need to change the sequence at the time of binding . 
At the time of binding or displaying data i need to show value of index 4 first and then at index 3.

Comment: Sort the source data and then bind to the Repeater. The binding on index has nothing to do with it.

Comment: I think you will have to implement your IEnumerable class and write it's enumerator as you wish

Comment: @VDWWD sorting can be done in ordered way. In my case I need index value to be displayed as : 1, 2, 4, 3 instead of  1, 2, 3, 4

Comment: @S.Petrosov can you please provide some example.

Comment: You can sort it any way you want. If you want it as 1,2,4,3 you can sort it like that before binding it to the repeater.

Answer (score 0):

Above is example of the `IEnumerable` class implemention, which will provide values in the order 1,2,4,3:

```
public class MyEnumerable<T> : IEnumerable<T>
{
    private List<T> _list;

    public MyEnumerable()
    {
        _list = new List<T>();
    }

    public void Add(T value)
    {
        _list.Add(value);
    }

    public bool Remove(T value)
    {
        return _list.Remove(value);
    }

    public bool Exists(Predicate<T> value)
    {
        return _list.Exists(value);
    }

    public bool Contains(T value)
    {
        return _list.Contains(value);
    }
    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < _list.Count; i++)
        {
            if (i == 2)
            {
                i++;
                yield return _list[i];
                yield return _list[i-1];
            }
            else
            {
                yield return _list[i];
            }
        }
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < _list.Count; i++)
        {
            if (i == 3)
            {
                yield return _list[i + 1];
                yield return _list[i];
                i += 2;
            }
            else
            {
                yield return _list[i];
                i++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But if your list will be more than 4 items you will need to change `GetEnumerator()` in accordingly to your needs.

And this is example which will print "First","Second","Third","Fourth" while in the List they will be in order "First","Second","Fourth","Third".

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    MyEnumerable<string> myEnumerable = new MyEnumerable<string>()
    {
        "First","Second","Fourth","Third"
    };
    foreach (var tmp in myEnumerable)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(tmp);
    }
}
```